# Solution Verification - Area between a Curve

Tags: solution-verification

Conflicted on whether I did this correctly. Any suggestions are appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your initial calculation of $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{49}{3}=\frac{50}{3}$ was correct for the two green areas

Your revised calculation of $5$ is correct for the purple area

What I do not know is whether the question is asking for the two green areas of $\frac{50}{3}$, or just the darker green area of $\frac{49}{3}$, or the purple area of $5$

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer. Does that look better?

Comment: @Eight8 - All your calculations of areas have been correct, both initial and revised.  I am not certain precisely which area you actually being asked for

Answer (score 0):

I think you've shaded the wrong region.  Here is a plot of the three curves in question:

[image]

The only region that is bounded by all three curves and no others, is the one between $x = 1$ and $x = 4$, and from $y = 1$ to $y = 16$.  Note you are not asked for the region below $y = \sqrt{x}$.

Therefore, the desired area is $$\int_{x=1}^4 x^2 - \sqrt{x} \, dx.$$ I leave the computation as an exercise.

Comment: Eight8 did that calculation as $\frac{49}{3}$.  Also the earlier small loop as $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer. Does that look better?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the area of the purple shaded region, that is not what you have.

That area would be $\int_0^1 x^2 \ dx + \int_1^4 \sqrt x$

But it is not clear that you in fact do want the that shaded area.  That would would include the boundary $y= 0$ which is not mentioned in the instructions.

My picture looks like:

[image]

Eventually the parabola will hit the line, but I truncated the picture.

Which is what your work shows.

You have an unexplained sign change at the last step.  It is not wrong, but I would get in front of it, rather than flipping a sign with no explanation.

$\int_0^4 |\sqrt x - x^2| \ dx =  \int_0^1 \sqrt x - x^2 \ dx + \int_1^4 x^2-\sqrt x \ dx$

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer. Does that look better?